# init function TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, html, css

No matter how I wrote the code, I received the same message and I've been trying to fix this since last night, but I don't understand why this is bothering me so much.

I get the message that all these lines are wrong

I work according to my course and this code is from a course that works on video and it doesn't work for me, I've tried a lot of changes but it doesn't work.

`document.getElementById('dice-1').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('dice-2').style.display = 'block';`

```
var scores, roundScore, activePlayer, gamePlaying;

var lastDice;


function init() {
    scores = [0, 0];
    activePlayer = 0;
    roundScore = 0;
    gamePlaying = true;

    document.getElementById('dice-1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('dice-2').style.display = 'none';

    document.getElementById('score-0').textContent = '0';
    document.getElementById('score-1').textContent = '0';
    document.getElementById('current-0').textContent = '0';
    document.getElementById('current-1').textContent = '0';
    document.getElementById('name-0').textContent = 'Player 1';
    document.getElementById('name-1').textContent = 'Player 2';
    document.querySelector('.player-0-panel').classList.remove('winner');
    document.querySelector('.player-1-panel').classList.remove('winner');
    document.querySelector('.player-0-panel').classList.remove('active');
    document.querySelector('.player-1-panel').classList.remove('active');
    document.querySelector('.player-0-panel').classList.add('active');
}

document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(gamePlaying) {
        var dice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        var dice2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

        document.getElementById('dice-1').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('dice-2').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('dice-1').src = 'dice-' + dice1 + '.png';
        document.getElementById('dice-2').src = 'dice-' + dice2 + '.png';

        if (dice1 !== 1 && dice2 !== 1) {
            roundScore += dice1 + dice2;
            document.querySelector('#current-' + activePlayer).textContent = roundScore;
        } else {
            nextPlayer();
        }
    }    
});


document.querySelector('.btn-hold').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (gamePlaying) {
        scores[activePlayer] += roundScore;

        document.querySelector('#score-' + activePlayer).textContent = scores[activePlayer];

        var input = document.querySelector('.final-score').value;
        var winningScore;

        if(input) {
            winningScore = input;
        } else {
            winningScore = 100;
        }

        // Check if player won the game
        if (scores[activePlayer] >= winningScore) {
            document.querySelector('#name-' + activePlayer).textContent = 'Winner!';
            document.getElementById('dice-1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('dice-2').style.display = 'none';
            document.querySelector('.player-' + activePlayer + '-panel').classList.add('winner');
            document.querySelector('.player-' + activePlayer + '-panel').classList.remove('active');
            gamePlaying = false;
        } else {
            nextPlayer();
        }
    }
});


function nextPlayer() {
    activePlayer === 0 ? activePlayer = 1 : activePlayer = 0;
    roundScore = 0;

    document.getElementById('current-0').textContent = '0';
    document.getElementById('current-1').textContent = '0';

    document.querySelector('.player-0-panel').classList.toggle('active');
    document.querySelector('.player-1-panel').classList.toggle('active');

    document.getElementById('dice-1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('dice-2').style.display = 'none';
}

document.querySelector('.btn-new').addEventListener('click', init);


init();
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Pig Game</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper clearfix">
            <div class="player-0-panel active">
                <div class="player-name" id="name-0">Player 1</div>
                <div class="player-score" id="score-0">43</div>
                <div class="player-current-box">
                    <div class="player-current-label">Current</div>
                    <div class="player-current-score" id="current-0">11</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="player-1-panel">
                <div class="player-name" id="name-1">Player 2</div>
                <div class="player-score" id="score-1">72</div>
                <div class="player-current-box">
                    <div class="player-current-label">Current</div>
                    <div class="player-current-score" id="current-1">0</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button class="btn-new"><i class="ion-ios-plus-outline"></i>New game</button>
            <button class="btn-roll"><i class="ion-ios-loop"></i>Roll dice</button>
            <button class="btn-hold"><i class="ion-ios-download-outline"></i>Hold</button>

            <input type="text" placeholder="Final Score" class="final-score">

            <img src="dice-5.png" alt="Dice" class="dice">
        </div>

        <script type='text/javascript' src="challenges.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
/**********************************************
*** GENERAL
**********************************************/

.final-score {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    top: 520px;
    color: #555;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 160px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.final-score:focus { outline: none; }

dice-1 { top: 120px; }
#dice-2 { top: 250px; }


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(62, 20, 20, 0.4), rgba(62, 20, 20, 0.4)), url(back.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    color: #555;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.player-0-panel,
.player-1-panel {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 600px;
    padding: 100px;
}



/**********************************************
*** PLAYERS
**********************************************/

.player-name {
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.player-score {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #EB4D4D;
    margin-bottom: 130px;
}

.active { background-color: #f7f7f7; }
.active .player-name { font-weight: 300; }

.active .player-name::after {
    content: "\2022";
    font-size: 47px;
    position: absolute;
    color: #EB4D4D;
    top: -7px;
    right: 10px;

}

.player-current-box {
    background-color: #EB4D4D;
    color: #fff;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}

.player-current-label {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #222;
}

.player-current-score {
    font-size: 30px;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    color: #555;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 300;
    transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}

button:hover { font-weight: 600; }
button:hover i { margin-right: 20px; }

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

i {
    color: #EB4D4D;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    margin-top: -4px;
    transition: margin 0.3s;
}

.btn-new { top: 45px;}
.btn-roll { top: 403px;}
.btn-hold { top: 467px;}

.dice {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 178px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
}

.winner { background-color: #f7f7f7; }
.winner .player-name { font-weight: 300; color: #EB4D4D; }
```

Please help me.

Comment: i updated the post take a look @Bahtiyar

Comment: What is the problem ? what do you mean  " that all these lines are wrong"

Comment: I found . problem is  "init" . check my answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

İn javascript  , remove  `init();`   or define init function.

try this:

```
function init() {
    scores = [0, 0];
    activePlayer = 0;
    roundScore = 0;
    gamePlaying = true;

    document.getElementById('dice-1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('dice-2').style.display = 'none';

    document.getElementById('score-0').textContent = '0';
    document.getElementById('score-1').textContent = '0';
    document.getElementById('current-0').textContent = '0';
    document.getElementById('current-1').textContent = '0';
    document.getElementById('name-0').textContent = 'Player 1';
    document.getElementById('name-1').textContent = 'Player 2';
    document.querySelector('.player-0-panel').classList.remove('winner');
    document.querySelector('.player-1-panel').classList.remove('winner');
    document.querySelector('.player-0-panel').classList.remove('active');
    document.querySelector('.player-1-panel').classList.remove('active');
    document.querySelector('.player-0-panel').classList.add('active');
}

document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(gamePlaying) {
        var dice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        var dice2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

        document.getElementById('dice-1').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('dice-2').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('dice-1').src = 'dice-' + dice1 + '.png';
        document.getElementById('dice-2').src = 'dice-' + dice2 + '.png';

        if (dice1 !== 1 && dice2 !== 1) {
            roundScore += dice1 + dice2;
            document.querySelector('#current-' + activePlayer).textContent = roundScore;
        } else {
            nextPlayer();
        }
    }    
});


document.querySelector('.btn-hold').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (gamePlaying) {
        scores[activePlayer] += roundScore;

        document.querySelector('#score-' + activePlayer).textContent = scores[activePlayer];

        var input = document.querySelector('.final-score').value;
        var winningScore;

        if(input) {
            winningScore = input;
        } else {
            winningScore = 100;
        }

        // Check if player won the game
        if (scores[activePlayer] >= winningScore) {
            document.querySelector('#name-' + activePlayer).textContent = 'Winner!';
            document.getElementById('dice-1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('dice-2').style.display = 'none';
            document.querySelector('.player-' + activePlayer + '-panel').classList.add('winner');
            document.querySelector('.player-' + activePlayer + '-panel').classList.remove('active');
            gamePlaying = false;
        } else {
            nextPlayer();
        }
    }
});


function nextPlayer() {
    activePlayer === 0 ? activePlayer = 1 : activePlayer = 0;
    roundScore = 0;

    document.getElementById('current-0').textContent = '0';
    document.getElementById('current-1').textContent = '0';

    document.querySelector('.player-0-panel').classList.toggle('active');
    document.querySelector('.player-1-panel').classList.toggle('active');

    document.getElementById('dice-1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('dice-2').style.display = 'none';
}
document.querySelector('.btn-new').addEventListener('click', init);


function init(){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any HTML elements with `id="dice-1"` nor `id="dice-2"`, which would explain the error you're receiving.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see element with id="dice-1" or id="dice-2" in your template (HTML), so the error just means, that element with that id doesn't exist, so it's value is null.